# Allow authenticated user to create an article

Tags: nodes

hey im fairly new to D7 and ive noticed that there isn't really a way to create an article without the admin toolbar, but i would like users of my websites to be able to create articles. How would i do this without giving them access to the toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to admin/people/permissions and check the permission "Article: create content"
and maybe on a block create a link for them called create content.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Admin->People->Permissions*, check the permission *Article: Create new content* for the Authenticated user.  Scroll down to the bottom and click *Save permissions*.  Now, there will appaear a link "*Add content*" in the navigation menu for the Authenticated user.

(There should be no need for you to create this link explicitly.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The permissions were turned on but I still couldn't see the toolbar.

**Solution:**
The "Add content" link for authenticated users was *in the sidebar*, **not** at the top, as it is for administrators. I had to scroll down to see the link.